# Plantilla con bootstrap no permite los estilos en la parte del footer pero en lo demás, sí

Tags: css, bootstrap

Use bootstrap para crear toda la platilla, al final quiero crear un footer con un fondo gris claro, pero es como que ahí, no me coge los estilos.

La plantilla

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">

    <title>Theme Template for Bootstrap</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lKuwvrZot6UHsBSfcMvOkWwlCMgc0TaWr+30HWe3a4ltaBwTZhyTEggF5tJv8tbt" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style3.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilos.css">
    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Bootstrap theme -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
    <link href="../../assets/css/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="theme.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Just for debugging purposes. Don't actually copy these 2 lines! -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="../../assets/js/ie8-responsive-file-warning.js"></script><![endif]-->
    <script src="../../assets/js/ie-emulation-modes-warning.js"></script>

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="jq/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jq/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>


    <!-- Fixed navbar navbar-fixed-top--> 
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse ">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">navbar-inverse</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <img src="ims/logo2.jpg" height="50" width="50"> 
        </div>

        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li ><a href="#">Solicitudes</a></li> <!--class="active" -->
            <li><a href="#">Certificados</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Administrativo</a></li>            
            <li><a href="#">Reportes</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Iniciar Sesión</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Estado de Trámites</a></li> 

          </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="slider">
      <div class="slides">
        <div class="slide">
          <img src="ims/11.jpg" alt="">
        </div>

        <div class="slide">
          <img src="ims/22.jpg" alt="">
        </div>

        <div class="slide">
          <img src="ims/3.png" alt="">
        </div>

        <div class="slide">
          <img src="ims/4.png" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div onclick="goLeft()" class="btnLeft fas fa-chevron-left"></div>
      <div onclick="goRight()" class="btnRight fas fa-chevron-right"></div>
    </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <h3 class="panel-title"><a href="#"> Solicitudes</a></h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
             <img src="ims/funcionario.jpg" height="200" width="320">
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="panel panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <h3 class="panel-title"><a href="carta_laboral.html">Carta laboral</a></h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
              <img src="ims/carta_laboral.jpg" height="200" width="320">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div><!-- /.col-sm-4 -->

        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <div class="panel panel-success">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <h3 class="panel-title"><a href="cesantias.html">Cesantías</a></h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
              <img src="ims/cesantias.jpg" height="200" width="320">
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="panel panel-info">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <h3 class="panel-title"><a href="permisos.html">Permisos</a></h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
              <img src="ims/permisos.png" height="200" width="320">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div><!-- /.col-sm-4 -->

        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <div class="panel panel-warning">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <h3 class="panel-title"><a href="capacitacion.html">Capacitación</a></h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
              <img src="ims/capacitacion.jpg" height="200" width="320">
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="panel panel-danger">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <h3 class="panel-title"><a href="nomina.html">Nomina</a></h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
              <img src="ims/nomina.jpg" height="200" width="320">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div><!-- /.col-sm-4 -->

        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <h3 class="panel-title"><a href="vacaciones.html"> Vacaciones</a></h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
             <img src="ims/vacaciones.jpg" height="200" width="320">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div><!-- /.col-sm-4 -->

        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <h3 class="panel-title"><a href="dia_del_funcionario.html"> Novedades</a></h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
             <img src="ims/novedades.jpg" height="200" width="320">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div><!-- /.col-sm-4 -->

        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <h3 class="panel-title"><a href="dia_del_funcionario.html"> Movimientos</a></h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
             <img src="ims/movimientos.jpg" height="200" width="320">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div><!-- /.col-sm-4 -->
    </div><!-- row -->



      <div class="footer" >        
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <div >
          <strong>Hospital General de Medellín</strong><br>
          El Hospital General de Medellín es una Empresa Social del Estado que presta servicios de salud hasta la alta complejidad, centrados en la seguridad del paciente, brindando afecto, confianza, satisfacción y promoviendo buenas prácticas ambientales y de calidad.
          </div> 
        </div>    
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <div > Conmutador: (574) 384 7300 Fax: (574) 232 0227<br>
              Carrera 48 No.32 - 102 Medellín - Colombia<br>
              Código postal 0500515<br>
              contacto@hgm.gov.co   <br><br>           

          </div>     
        </div>      
      </div><!-- footer -->      


    </div> <!-- /container -->


    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="../../assets/js/vendor/jquery.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
    <script src="../../dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../../assets/js/docs.min.js"></script>
    <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
    <script src="../../assets/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("slide");
  var index = 0;
  function goLeft() {
    if(index == 0) index = slides.length - 1;
    else index--;

    slides[0].style.marginLeft = "-" + index * 600 + "px";
  }
  function goRight() {
    if(index == slides.length -1) index = 0;
    else index++;

    slides[0].style.marginLeft = "-" + index * 600 + "px";
  }

  //for auto Navigation
</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

estilos.css

```
    body{
    margin:0;   
    color:#6a6f8c;  
    font:600 16px/18px 'Open Sans',sans-serif;
}



html {
    height: 100%;
}



#contact {
    background: #728eaa;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #25303C 0%, #728EAA 100%); /* firefox */  
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#25303C), color-stop(100%,#728EAA)); /* webkit */
    font-family: sans-serif; 

    width: 520px; margin: 60px auto; padding: 60px 30px;
    height: 590px;
    background: #c9d0de; border: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px #444;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px #444;

}

h1 {
    font-size: 35px; color: #445668; text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center; margin: 0 0 35px 0; text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #f2f2f2;

}

label {
    float: left; 
    clear: left; 
    margin: 11px 20px 0 0; 
    width: 200px;
    text-align: right; 
    font-size: 14px; 
    color: #445668; 
    text-transform: uppercase; 
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #f2f2f2;

}

input {
    width: 230px;
    height: 20px;
    padding: 5px 20px 0px 20px;
    margin: 0 0 20px 0; 
    background: #5E768D;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #546A7F 0%, #5E768D 20%); /* firefox */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#546A7F), color-stop(20%,#5E768D)); /* webkit */
    border-radius: 5px; -moz-border-radius: 5px; -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #f2f2f2;-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #f2f2f2;
    font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 16px; color: #f2f2f2; text-transform: uppercase; text-shadow: 0px -1px 0px #334f71; 
}
    input::-webkit-input-placeholder  {
        color: #a1b2c3; text-shadow: 0px -1px 0px #38506b;  
    }
    input:-moz-placeholder {
        color: #a1b2c3; text-shadow: 0px -1px 0px #38506b; 
    }

textarea {
    width: 260px; height: 170px; padding: 12px 20px 0px 20px; margin: 0 0 20px 0; 
    background: #5E768D;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #546A7F 0%, #5E768D 20%); /* firefox */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#546A7F), color-stop(20%,#5E768D)); /* webkit */
    border-radius: 5px; -moz-border-radius: 5px; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #f2f2f2;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #f2f2f2;
    font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 16px; color: #f2f2f2; text-transform: uppercase; text-shadow: 0px -1px 0px #334f71; 
}
    textarea::-webkit-input-placeholder  {
        color: #a1b2c3; text-shadow: 0px -1px 0px #38506b;  
    }
    textarea:-moz-placeholder {
        color: #a1b2c3; text-shadow: 0px -1px 0px #38506b; 
    }

input:focus, textarea:focus {
    background: #728eaa;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #668099 0%, #728eaa 20%); /* firefox */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#668099), color-stop(20%,#728eaa)); /* webkit */
}

input[type=submit] {
    /*float: right; */
    width: 185px; height: 52px;  padding: 10px 15px; margin: 0 15px 0 0;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #999;-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #999;
    border: 1px solid #556f8c;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #718DA9 0%, #415D79 100%); /* firefox */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#718DA9), color-stop(100%,#415D79)); /* webkit */
    cursor: pointer;
}

input[type=button] {
    /*float: right; */
    width: 185px; height: 52px;  padding: 10px 15px; margin: 0 15px 0 0;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #999;-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #999;
    border: 1px solid #556f8c;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #718DA9 0%, #415D79 100%); /* firefox */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#718DA9), color-stop(100%,#415D79)); /* webkit */
    cursor: pointer;
}
.footer{
    background: #728eaa;
}
```

Tengo otros archivos pero no veo nada en esos estilos.

Comment: Mira si tienes bien añadida la libreria a mi desde [aqui](https://codepen.io/DonKaoz/pen/NJBEZb) si me la muestra bien

Comment: Procura agregar tu hoja de estilos `estilos.css` despues de las librerias de Bootstrap y otras del template para que tu estilo sea el ultimo en aplicar